# Rank a value for its respective category in Microsoft Excel or Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

Let say I have a dataset of car selling. I want to rank each car product for its category.
Right now, I can get this by using this formula.

```
=rank(C2,filter(C$2:$C,B$2:$B=B6))
```

This formula works fine, except that I have to copy this for each row. I see an array formula, but I can not figure out how to use it.

[image: Car Rank by Category]

Here is the
[Sample Workbook Car Selling](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lv1ky1d8gv7IDh7yMuijhndlfflQmDM-eTOe2tNaz60/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Harun24HR, the result is different. I tried that way too. Here is the sample workbook link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lv1ky1d8gv7IDh7yMuijhndlfflQmDM-eTOe2tNaz60/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=arrayformula(iferror(VLOOKUP(row(B2:B),{sort({row(B2:B),B2:C},2,1,3,0),row(B2:B)},4,false)-MATCH((B2:B),QUERY({sort({B2:C},1,1,2,0)},"select Col1"),0)))
```

### explanation

1- the key to the solution is to play with a virtual database sorted by cotegory and value where I add the current row after sorting

```
{row(B2:B),B2:C},2,1,3,0),row(B2:B)}
```

I will search within this virtual database for a "global ranking"

```
=arrayformula(VLOOKUP(row(B2:B),{sort({row(B2:B),B2:C},2,1,3,0),row(B2:B)},4,false))
```

2- the second step is to work with the only category within the same sorting process

```
QUERY({sort({B2:C},1,1,2,0)},"select Col1")
```

and retrieve the first line where the category appears

```
=arrayformula(iferror(MATCH((B2:B),QUERY({sort({B2:C},1,1,2,0)},"select Col1"),0)))
```

3- and at the end you subtract the two values

Comment: Yes, I will add the full development later